# How to set d3 color scale for each element in object array?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am generating a HTML table using `d3` for an object array. I want to color background with gradient level depending on the value range.

I used a category10 domain scale colors applied for columns without gradient. Is there anyway to specify min max to `d3` and set gradient. This is the result I am getting I need make linear values of engine torque with gradient and categorical Engine Type with different colors depending on value

[image]

Data array looks like this

```
 [{ EngineType="Piston",  torque=10,  rpm=1}, { EngineType="Piston",  torque=10,  rpm=1}]
```

Javascript code

```
var color = d3.scale.category10()
    .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)]);

var rows = d3.select('tbody')
    .selectAll('tr')
    .data(data, function(d) { return d[config.key]})

var entertd = rows.enter()
    .append('tr')
        .selectAll('td')
            .data(function(d) { return d3.map(d).values() })
        .enter()
            .append('td')
            .attr('bgcolor',color)

entertd.append('span')
var td = rows.selectAll('td')
.style({"padding": "0px 10px 0px 10px"})
    .data(function(d) { return d3.map(d).entries() })
    .attr('class', function (d) { return d.key })

td.select('span')
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.value
    })
```

Similar scenario in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WQjr/1032/)

Comment: Can you create a snippet or bin for this question? It will be much easier to help you that way..

Comment: @MoshFeu I reproduced similar scenario in a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/7WQjr/1032/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to convert the color from `category10()` to a gradient based on this color.

If so:

1. you can use the function `.ColorLuminance()` I found [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-generate-lighter-darker-color/) to get a lighter color so we can create a gradient by the both colors.
2. Set the background as gradient using `.attr()` like you did, but instead of `bgcolor`, set `style:backougrnd` like this: `attr('style','background:linear-gradient(to bottom, ' + color(0) + ' 0%,' + ColorLuminance(color(0), 0.5) + ' 100%)');`

**The full code:**

```js
function tabulate(data, columns) {
  var table = d3.select("#container").append("table"),
      thead = table.append("thead"),
      tbody = table.append("tbody");

  // append the header row
  thead.append("tr")
  .selectAll("th")
  .data(columns)
  .enter()
  .append("th")
  .text(function(column) { return column; });

  // create a row for each object in the data
  var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("tr");


  //Color scale
  var color = d3.scale.category10()
  .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(d3.values(data))]);

  // create a cell in each row for each column
  var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
  .data(function(row) {
    return columns.map(function(column) {
      return {column: column, value: row[column]};
    });
  })
  .enter()
  .append("td")
  .text(function(d) { return d.value; }).attr('style','background:linear-gradient(to bottom, ' + color(0) + ' 0%,' + ColorLuminance(color(0), 0.5) + ' 100%)');

  return table;
}

var people = [
  {EngineType: "Rotary", torque: 30, rpm: 21},
  {EngineType: "Piston", torque: 32, rpm: 23},
  {EngineType: "Rotary", torque: 29, rpm: 21},
  {EngineType: "Piston", torque: 31, rpm: 12}
];

// render the table
var peopleTable = tabulate(people, ["EngineType", "torque", "rpm"]);

// uppercase the column headers
peopleTable.selectAll("thead th")
.text(function(column) {
  return column.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + column.substr(1);
});

// sort by age
peopleTable.selectAll("tbody tr")
.sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.descending(a.age, b.age);
});

function ColorLuminance(hex, lum) {

 // validate hex string
 hex = String(hex).replace(/[^0-9a-f]/gi, '');
 if (hex.length < 6) {
  hex = hex[0]+hex[0]+hex[1]+hex[1]+hex[2]+hex[2];
 }
 lum = lum || 0;

 // convert to decimal and change luminosity
 var rgb = "#", c, i;
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  c = parseInt(hex.substr(i*2,2), 16);
  c = Math.round(Math.min(Math.max(0, c + (c * lum)), 255)).toString(16);
  rgb += ("00"+c).substr(c.length);
 }

 return rgb;
}
```

```css
td, th {
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

http://jsbin.com/qalaxu/edit?js

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort, Actually i need to add gradient to whole column where as 32 is the darkest color, 29 is the lightest.  remaining should be gradient in between two

Comment: Do you mean that each cell should be have a solid gradient but the all the backgrounds looks like gradient?

Comment: yes cell is a solid color but whole column is gradient and high values are darker and low values are lighter

Answer (score 0):

You can try colorScale.https://bl.ocks.org/pstuffa/d5934843ee3a7d2cc8406de64e6e4ea5
e.g.

```
var colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3["interpolate" + scaleName])
    .domain([0,10]);
```

Then assign each cell a color

```
var td = rows.selectAll('td')
    .style({"padding": "0px 10px 0px 10px"})
    .data(function(d) { return d3.map(d).entries() })
    .attr('class', function (d) { return d.key })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value); });
```